# How to align two divs side by side using the float, clear, and overflow elements with a fixed position div/

Tags: css, html

So I've been trying to align two divs side by side without overlapping. I have one div which will be fixed as a sidebar and the right div as the content. Hopefully, someone can help me.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1005px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #111;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: fixed;
}

#rightcolumn {
  width: 750px;
  background-color: #777;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftcolumn">
  </div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you either user position:Fixed or float - not both.

Comment: @peterchon I removed the float element is there something there to add or to change?

Comment: If your right column is the content, then why is it so much skinnier?

Comment: You could try with flexbox or table layout (depending on target browsers). If you're using float, remember to always add `clear: both` after last element as you probably don't want anything else showing there.

Comment: @crush thank you for letting me know, I had this as a project and decided to change some things and just edited.

Comment: @maremp where should I add the `clear: both`?

Comment: Since you want the left column fixed to the left side of the page, should we assume you mean you don't want it to scroll if the page were to scroll?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This answer may have to be modified depending on what you were trying to achieve with `position: fixed;`.  If all you want is two columns side by side then do the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/8weSA/1/

I floated both columns to the left.

**Note:** I added `min-height` to each column for illustrative purposes and I simplified your CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1005px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn,
#rightcolumn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  min-height: 450px;
  color: white;
}

#leftcolumn {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #111;
}

#rightcolumn {
  width: 750px;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftcolumn">
    Left
  </div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

If you would like the left column to stay in place as you scroll do the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/8weSA/2/

Here we float the right column to the right while adding `position: relative;` to `#wrapper` and `position: fixed;` to `#leftcolumn`.

**Note:** I again used `min-height` for illustrative purposes and can be removed for your needs.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1005px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#leftcolumn,
#rightcolumn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  min-height: 750px;
  color: white;
}

#leftcolumn {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #111;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

#rightcolumn {
  width: 750px;
  background-color: #777;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftcolumn">
    Left
  </div>
  <div id="rightcolumn">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This one looks great as well.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="float left">left</div>
    <div class="float right">right</div>
</div>

#wrapper {
   width:500px; 
   height:300px; 
   position:relative;
}

.float {
   background-color:black; 
   height:300px; 
   margin:0; 
   padding:0; 
   color:white;
}

.left {
   background-color:blue; 
   position:fixed; 
   width:400px;
}

.right {
   float:right; 
   width:100px;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khA4m

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I customized it a little and now I'm on track for how I wanted to style it.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>AutoDealer</title>
        <style>
        .container{
            width: 860px;
            height: 1074px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            border: 1px solid red;

        }
        .nav{

        }
        .wrapper{
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
       .otherWrapper{
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid green;
            float:left;
        }
    .left{
        width: 399px;
        float: left;
        background-color: pink;
    }
            .bottom{
        clear: both;
        width: 399px;
        background-color: yellow;



    }
    .right{
        height:350px;
        width: 449px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: blue;
        overflow: hidden;
        float:right;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="otherWrapper">
            <div class="left">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ultricies aliquet tellus sit amet ultrices. Sed faucibus, nunc vitae accumsan laoreet, enim metus varius nulla, ac ultricies felis ante venenatis justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In cursus enim nec urna molestie, id mattis elit mollis. In sed eros eget nibh congue vehicula. Nunc vestibulum enim risus, sit amet suscipit dui auctor et. Morbi orci magna, accumsan at turpis a, scelerisque congue eros. Morbi non mi vel nibh varius blandit sed et urna.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="bottom">
                <p>ucibus eros, sed viverra ex. Vestibulum aliquet accumsan massa, at feugiat ipsum interdum blandit. Morbi et orci hendrerit orci consequat ornare ac et sapien. Nulla vestibulum lectus bibendum, efficitur purus in, venenatis nunc. Nunc tincidunt velit sit amet orci pellentesq</p></div>
             </div>

             <div class="right">
                <p>Quisque vulputate mi id turpis luctus, quis laoreet nisi vestibulum. Morbi facilisis erat vitae augue ornare convallis. Fusce sit amet magna rutrum, hendrerit purus vitae, congue justo. Nam non mi eget purus ultricies lacinia. Fusce ante nisl, efficitur venenatis urna ut, pellentesque egestas nisl. In ut faucibus eros, sed viverra ex. Vestibulum aliquet accumsan massa, at feugiat ipsum interdum blandit. Morbi et orci hendrerit orci consequat ornare ac et sapien. Nulla vestibulum lectus bibendum, efficitur purus in, venenatis nunc. Nunc tincidunt velit sit amet orci pellentesque maximus. Quisque a tempus lectus.</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So basically I just made another div to wrap the pink and yellow, and I make that div have a float:left on it. The blue div has a float:right on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Kindly mark small correction.

```
#rightcolumn {
     width: 750px;
     background-color: #777;
     display: block;
     **float: left;(wrong)**
     **float: right; (corrected)**
     border: 1px solid white;
}
```