# How to get a 2x2 grid of divs

Tags: html, css

How would I achieve a grid layout similar to the one below through the use of CSS and HTML? I've attempted the use of floating and margins, but that's only allowed me to replicate the first row.
[image: Div grid]

Current HTML

```
<div id="lens_logo"><img src="images/about-lens.png"></div>
<div id="lightfield_logo"></div>
<div id="body_logo"></div>
<div id="spec_logo"></div>
```

Current CSS

```
#lens_logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
}

#lightfield_logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
}

#body_logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#spec_logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Which produces this result:
[image: Current]

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Have you tried... tables?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344904/how-to-align-two-divs-side-by-side-using-the-float-clear-and-overflow-elements Shows you how to put two side by side, and then it should easy enough to add in the same again underneath

Comment: @Jackhardcastle - tables shouldn't be used for layout.

Comment: @j08691, I know, sarcasm implied.

Comment: More information has been added.

Comment: Why do you have left margins on the divs? Just clear the third div and you should be fine.

Comment: @j08691 It was intended to space them out a bit from each other, there's probably better ways of doing it... Anyway, clearing the third div of the margin just ends up putting it all onto one row, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: When I said clear the third div, I meant like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4ht4fvho/1/ (sizes changed for easier viewing)

Comment: @j08691 Ahhh, alright, cheers! Didn't know that was a thing, haha.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because the question is on hold (I voted to reopen it but it still needs four more votes)

Comment: @j08691 Yeah, realized just after I posted the comment and edited it to match, guess you got there before I did! Thank you anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend bootstrap for stuff like this http://getbootstrap.com/

It's grid system is really powerful and easy to use.

You could implement this grid using an expansion of the following snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
</div>
```

To implement the spaces between the divs you can either use the bootstrap offset css classes or give your divs custom classes and put the margins in there.

Comment: Then again, he's likely to be a beginner so he may not have seen this!

Comment: Yeah, it might be a bit overkill, but I'm thinking that this isn't the only place in the code that he might want to do some sort of layout, so having the framework in place from the start may be helpful. And anything to get rid of having to deal with css floats is something I'm up for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the four divs in a container the size you want and float each div to the sides.  So wrapping container could be:

```
.grid {
  width: 750px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnumjd1q/