# Aligning multiple divs side by side

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align multiple divs side by side. 
I have searched stackoverflow and based my code on this: [How to align two divs side by side using the float, clear, and overflow elements with a fixed position div/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344904/how-to-align-two-divs-side-by-side-using-the-float-clear-and-overflow-elements).

I've played around with it, and ended up with this css:

```
    .frontpageBoxLeft, .frontpageBoxRight {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
}

.frontpageBoxLeft {
  margin-bottom:15px;
  width: 750px;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.frontpageBoxRight {
  width: 320px;
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.frontpageBoxContainer {
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

and this html:

```
  <div class="frontpageBoxContainer">
<p class="newsfeedheadline">NEWS FEED</p>
<hr class="hrstarter">
<div class="frontpageBoxLeft" id="1">
     et eksempel på en kasse1
</div>
<div class="frontpageBoxLeft" id="2">
     et eksempel på en kasse2
</div>
<div class="frontpageBoxLeft" id="3">
     et eksempel på en kasse3
</div>
<div class="frontpageBoxRight">
     et eksempel på en anden kasse
</div>
</div>
```

The result is this:

[div alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyB29.png)

I would like to be able to put multiple divs on the left side, and multiple divs on the right side.
Right now the code works fine when iam only using one right and one left div, but with multiple divs it act like in the picture.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.frontpageBoxLeft,
.frontpageBoxRight {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
}

.left-container {
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
}

.frontpageBoxLeft {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 750px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.frontpageBoxRight {
  width: 540px;
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.frontpageBoxContainer {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="frontpageBoxContainer">
<p class="newsfeedheadline">NEWS FEED</p>
<hr class="hrstarter">
  <div class="left-container">
  <div class="frontpageBoxLeft" id="1">
     et eksempel på en kasse1
</div>
<div class="frontpageBoxLeft" id="2">
     et eksempel på en kasse2
</div>
<div class="frontpageBoxLeft" id="3">
     et eksempel på en kasse3
</div>
  </div>

<div class="frontpageBoxRight">
     et eksempel på en anden kasse
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you've taken a screenshot of above? It looks like what I need, but when I try with the css you provide, I don't get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this might help you

```css
div{
  width: 48%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

or this one

```css
div{
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works very well with an even number of divs on each side, but in my case, I need support for more divs on the left side, properly 20-30 divs and only 1 or two divs on the right side.

Comment: What if I wanted it to keep going right and not go to the next line? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119889/how-to-put-multiple-divs-side-by-side-and-not-go-to-the-next-line

Answer (score 0):

Put `float: left` to the `.frontpageBoxLeft` selector will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try set the `frontpageBoxContainer` to `position:relative`
2. Float the left AND the right Containers.
3. set `left` or `right` Offset to the divs you want to align.