# How to put multiple divs side by side and not go to the next line

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29xxju45/

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 2%;
  background: #0000CC;
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.minhold {
      z-index: 10;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 0.4%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    opacity: 0.97;
    filter: alpha(opacity=97);
    width: 99%;
    float: left;
}
.dmaxh {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 31%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 10px 1%;
}
.main-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    background: rgb(71, 194, 243);
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```

Even though the parent div (`.minhold`) is hidden, how can I make it so that BOX 3 and BOX 4 (or any subsequent boxes) are next to BOX 2 and not go to the next line.

I want any extra divs that doesn't fit in the main container to be hidden so I can use an arrow to go right and left.

[Aligning multiple divs side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125435/aligning-multiple-divs-side-by-side) didn't work me if anyone wants to mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a container class and use the `calc` attribute on width...for example:

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="minhold">
    <div class="container" style="background: red;"></div>
    <div class="container" style="background: blue;"></div>
    <div class="container" style="background: green;"></div>
    <div class="container" style="background: pink;"></div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ae8zac59/2/)

In a nutshell, each container calculates it's parent width and gets divided by 4 (since you have 4 containers).  If you want more containers, simply put 5 or more in place of 4.

Comment: Actually I want it to be hidden so I can use an arrow to go right and left... sorry i wasn't clear.

Comment: add `overflow: hidden;` and a fixed `height` to your parent class `.minhold` - Although, it sounds as though you are wanting a slider/slideshow....

Answer (score 1):

you have to define height and set `overflow:auto;`

Here is code: https://jsfiddle.net/29xxju45/2/

**EDIT**

for horizontal scrollbar

https://jsfiddle.net/29xxju45/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use FlexModel.

```css
.minhold {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 0.4%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    opacity: 0.97;
    filter: alpha(opacity=97);
    width: 99%;
    float: left;
}
.dmaxh {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 31%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 10px 1%;
}
.main-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    background: rgb(71, 194, 243);
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #990000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; margin: -1.6rem 0 0 0;">
         <div class="main-content">
          
            <div class="maxh" style="overflow: hidden !important;">
<div class="minhold">
  <div class="box" style="background: #009900;">
    BOX 1
  </div>
    <div class="box" style="background: #990000;">
    BOX 2
  </div>
    <div class="box" style="background: #000099;">
    BOX 3
  </div>
    <div class="box" style="background: #999;">
    BOX 4
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i updated my question... I want it to be hidden so i can scroll to next div or previous div.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you're hard coding the widths into each div, and the math doesn't check out. If you were to apply a `block` class to each div and apply a `width: 25%` you would fit four blocks side by side.

Updated Fiddled:
https://jsfiddle.net/29xxju45/1/