# How can I place the two grid views near each other?

Tags: html

I am making a website from scratch. I saw the grid views in w3school and thought  of using it. Anyway, I used the float left in my .whole element but it's not working. I already tried changing it to clear left but it's not working too. Could someone help me place the two .sections element next to each other?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #9933cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-3 {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

.sections {
  width: 1300px;
}

.whole {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Chania</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-3 menu">
        <ul>
          <li>The Flight</li>
          <li>The City</li>
          <li>The Island</li>
          <li>The Food</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <h1>The City</h1>
        <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sections">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Chania</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-3 menu">
        <ul>
          <li>The Flight</li>
          <li>The City</li>
          <li>The Island</li>
          <li>The Food</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <h1>The City</h1>
        <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aside from my comment, this definitely has been posted before so check out similar questions like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344904/how-to-align-two-divs-side-by-side-using-the-float-clear-and-overflow-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align two divs side by side using the float, clear, and overflow elements with a fixed position div/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344904/how-to-align-two-divs-side-by-side-using-the-float-clear-and-overflow-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Theres multiple options but one is that you can put `position: relative;` on the `.whole` and then `position: absolute;` and `width: 50%;` on the `.section` (with some type of min-width specified too). Then on the first `.section` div you can add `left: 0;` and on the other `.section` you can add `right: 0;`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #9933cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-3 {width: 15%;}
    .col-6 {width: 20%;}
}
.sections {
width: 50%;
min-width: 500px;
position: absolute;
}

.sections.left {
  left: 0;
}

.sections.right {
  right: 0;
}

.whole {
position: relative;
top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="whole">
<div class="sections left">
<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="sections right">
<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then just adjust widths on some of the child elements of .section. You don't apply a float to the parent if you want the child elements floated, but furthermore you had a 1300px width on the child elements which would've caused an issue for you too.

Comment: I set that to 1300px width so that the content won't be so merged and it will not come out of the div container when I resize it. I tried yours and when I resize it to 33% the content comes out and when I resize it to 150%-250% it kind of overlaps.. :(

Comment: You can't set width to 50% and then just set a min-width and max-width?

Comment: I used your code and retained my width: 1000px  in .sections. And the content doesn't come out anymore. The only problem now is when I resize it to 110% it overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] { 
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #9933cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li { 
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-3 {width: 15%;} 
    .col-6 {width: 20%;} 
}
.sections {
width: 50%;
float:left;
}
.whole {
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="whole">
<div class="sections">
<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="sections">
<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```