# Div gets put in div above

Tags: html, css

So I want to put the two divs next to each other and the one below in the code gets put into the one above and I have no idea why.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="links">
        <h1 id="title">Webcam</h1>
        <?php

            $dateinamen = 'pictures/Live.jpg';
            $timestamp = filemtime($dateinamen);
            $time  = time();
            $diff = $time -$timestamp;

            // Wenn Bild jünger als 10sec
            if ($diff < 10){
                echo "<img src='pictures/Live.jpg'";  
            } 
            else {
                echo "<img src='pictures/oops.jpg'";
            }
        ?> 
    </div>

    <div id="rechts">
        <h2>Ping</h2>
        <?php

            $host1="192.168.1.1";
            exec("ping -c 1 -w 1 " . $host1, $output1, $result1);
            if ($result1 == 0) {
                echo "<h3 id='sw1'style='background-color: green';>Router</h3></br>";
            }else {
                echo "<h3 id='sw1'style='background-color: red';>Router</h3></br>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#links{
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

#rechts{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
```

Haven't found any cases like these so I don't know if it's a problem with xampp or something else.

**EDIT**
[Photo in inspection mode in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtj7F.png)

Comment: use float : left; for both divs , check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344904/how-to-align-two-divs-side-by-side-using-the-float-clear-and-overflow-elements/18345124

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close the img tag used in the PHP code.

```
use <img src='pictures/Live.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox instead.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#links{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}

#rechts{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="links">
        <h1 id="title">Webcam</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="rechts">
        <h2>Ping</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No need to post a whole answer just for 1 sentence. A comment would have been enought.

Comment: I've tried that already, the div still gets put into the "links" div

Comment: Edited the answer to provide a flexbox-based solution

Comment: just tried that, it simply puts the situation like it is now into another div... I really don't know why it would do that, the code is on the same line and in Notepad it literally displays it that I've closed the div before opening the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check by removing margin-top:7%; form this class

```
#rechts {
float: right;
width: 50%;
// margin-top: 7%;  remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just got trolled...
I just switched the two divs around (using the Flexbox solution proposed by [Michał Drabik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10169826/micha%c5%82-drabik)) and it worked...

Comment: I would guess that switching the order makes it work because of the unclosed `img` tags that Sameeksha Kumari pointed out in their answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784496/10146245) - the unclosed tags will mess up what comes after them, so if the other div is before instead of after, the problem will be concealed